# Android Instagram API: how to retrieve pictures

Tags: android, webview, inputstream, instagram, httpsurlconnection

I'm building an Android app that uses the Instagram API to retrieve Instagram images and then display them in my app.

I've been trying to make it work using the only tutorial I found on [this](http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/instagram-api-integration-in-android-application/2/), 
which is same as [this](http://grishma102.blogspot.ca/2014/01/instagram-api-integration-in-android.html).

I've been able to the first part by loading the Instagram authentication in a Webview, but I'm having trouble with the second part which is actually getting images from my Instagram account by getting the Instagram imageUrl.

Specifically I'm having trouble with this part:

```
class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

static String accessTokenString, id, username, urlString, imageUrlString;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

   try {
   URL url = new URL(tokenURLString);
   HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
   httpsURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
   httpsURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
   OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream());
   outputStreamWriter.write("client_id="+client_id+
                                    "client_secret="+ client_secret +
                                    "grant_type=authorization_code" +
                                    "redirect_uri="+CALLBACKURL+
                                    "code=" + token);
   outputStreamWriter.flush();

   Log.i(TAG, "before streamToString");       

   String response = streamToString(httpsURLConnection.getInputStream());

   Log.i(TAG, "after streamToString");

   JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();

   accessTokenString = jsonObject.getString("access_token"); //Here is your ACCESS TOKEN
   id = jsonObject.getJSONObject("user").getString("id");
   username = jsonObject.getJSONObject("user").getString("username"); 
   //This is how you can get the user info. 
   //You can explore the JSON sent by Instagram as well to know what info you got in a response
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "ERROR AsyncTask");
    }

    return null;
    }

    //converts Stream to String
    public String streamToString(InputStream p_is)
    {
       try
       {
             BufferedReader m_br;
             StringBuffer m_outString = new StringBuffer();
             m_br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p_is));
             String m_read = m_br.readLine();
             while(m_read != null)
             {
               m_outString.append(m_read);
               m_read =m_br.readLine();
             }

             Log.d(TAG, "m_outString: " + m_outString.toString());
            return m_outString.toString();
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           Log.e(TAG, "ERROR streamToString");
       }

       return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Executed AsyncTask");
    }

        @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.d(TAG, "About to execute AsyncTask");
    }

        @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```

I'm wondering what the token variable is? (doInBackground method, in the outStreamWriter arguments)

I'm currently putting the request_token from the AuthWebViewClient.
The AuthWebViewClient is getting a request_token from Instagram successfully after I press Authorize in my WebView.

But I get an error when trying to turn the InputStream to a String!

```
06-16 14:14:42.302: D/tellmeaboutit(31244): About to execute AsyncTask
06-16 14:14:42.642: I/tellmeaboutit(31244): request_token: 235958nvzdj243u9o974jd1490139238
06-16 14:14:42.642: I/tellmeaboutit(31244): before streamToString
06-16 14:14:42.792: D/tellmeaboutit(31244): ERROR AsyncTask
```

Prints "before streamToString" then "ERROR AsyncTask" and never reaches "after streamToString".

I'm starting the LongOperation with a button click:

```
doSomethingIunno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new LongOperation().execute("");
        }

    });
```

What's wrong here? Why do I get an error when I try and convert the InputStream to a String?

Answer (score 3):

Well, instead of building your own code, why don't you try to use this [library](https://github.com/3pillarlabs/socialauth-android/) instead ? Look at the custom-ui example on "instagram get feeds" part.